# Get height of view

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I would like to get a `View` height what I'm inflating from another `xml` file. I'm always getting 0 as a height with these:

```
fun getHeight(): Int {
    val factory = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    val inflater = context?.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    val customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_expandable_helper,null)
    val relativeLayout = customView.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.container_height)
    val textView = customView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_height)
    textView.text = complaintText
    val rlp = RelativeLayout(activity)
    rlp.addView(customView)

    activity?.window?.decorView!!.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : OnGlobalLayoutListener{
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            val obs = relativeLayout.viewTreeObserver
            viewHeight = relativeLayout.height
            obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
        }
    })

    val hei = rlp.height
    relativeLayout.post {
        viewHeight = relativeLayout.height
    }
    return relativeLayout.height
}
```

In this code you can see many of shots to get the height and all of them are 0.

And this is the xml what I'm inflating:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
android:id="@+id/container_height">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_height"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/et_sides"
    android:text="sample.sample.sample.sample.sample.sample.sample.sample.sample.sample.sample.sample.sample.sample.sample.sample.sample.sample."/>
```

Comment: View Height is an integer or long?

Comment: It is an interger

Answer (score 0):

You should use OnGlobalLayoutListener to listen to view layout changes because when you inflated the view its sizes are not measured yet.

P.S.
Sorry for example in JAVA

```
relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // remove this once the layout measured
                relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
                int height = lp.height; // Here we retrieve the measured height

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now when I check the height at `lp.height` it's not 0 but it's -2 and I expected 522.

Answer (score 0):

A view will only return a non-zero height or width once it is already laid out on screen. That is the reason why we use `ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener`, `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener`, etc.

Now that method won't work since you are simply returning `return relativeLayout.height` which would always be zero.

So in other words, the only part of your code where you could get the view height is:

```
activity?.window?.decorView!!.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : 
OnGlobalLayoutListener{
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            val obs = relativeLayout.viewTreeObserver
            viewHeight = relativeLayout.height
            obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
        }
    })
```

If you log that `viewHeight` in there that should print the correct height of your view.

try this

```
    val vto = activity?.window?.decorView?.viewTreeObserver?
    vto?.addOnPreDrawListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
                override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
                vto?.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
                val viewHeight = relativeLayout.height
                Log.v("logtag", viewHeight)
            }
        })
```

If you are not going to Load that layout do this:

```
val view = yourView
val widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
val heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.height, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)

val childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec, parent.paddingLeft+parent.paddingRight,view.layoutParams.width)
val childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec, parent.paddingTop+parent.paddingBottom, view.layoutParams.height)

view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as I said in the description all part of the code which gives me the height is zero, including the part inside `onGlobalLayout()`. But sorry if I misunderstand what you are trying to say.

Comment: How were you logging the Height? are you calling your method like Log.v("logtag", tHeight())? Coz if thats how youre doing it you'll really get a 0 height.

Comment: try activity?.window?.decorView?.viewTreeObserver?.addOnPreDrawListener(
                object : ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
            override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
                activity?.window?.decorView?.viewTreeObserver?.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
                val viewHeight = relativeLayout.height
                Log.v("lagtag", viewHeight)
            }
        })

Comment: Thank you unfortunately it gives me 0 too. But think your idea is close to the solution because if load this view using setContentView then I'm able to get the height.

Comment: Oh i think i misunderstood your question. So you are not inflating that layout thaterefore that reallywont have a measure you should Measure it first.

Comment: see my updated answer. Though, i think you should layout the view first before you could have a measured dimension.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, parentHeight);
super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And how should I call this? This method inherits from a View parent so I should create a class which inherits a View?